# My network manager applet is dumb?

Tags: network-manager, applet, connection, modem

I'm using a modem to connect to internet,
may be because of poor signal strength my internet gets disconnected often,
but when it does network manager applet have to show that I've been disconnected but it doesn't. is this the problem with my modem or the applet?
I've been using ping command in a terminal window to check my connection

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have the option to upgrade your Ubuntu to v.11.04 and it will be fixed automatically !! I fixed a laptop and a desktop using this solution !!! They say it's a bug !!!

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 11.10 beta